# matrix_basis isn't affected correctly

Tags: python, transforms

I'd like to set the **`matrix_basis`** of an object. Unfortunately, the matrix isn't get updated correctly.

This is my test scene, consisting of an plane and a cylinder object:
[image: example scene]

My objective is to get `alpha`, the plane's x angle, and apply it in some way to cylinder.

Here is the code:

```
import bpy
from math import *
from mathutils import *

plane = bpy.data.objects['plane']
cylinder = bpy.data.objects['cylinder']
 
alpha = plane.rotation_euler[0] # x rotation
print('alpha=%.2f' % degrees(alpha))

'''
# normal rotation matrix around x axis
# works fine
m = Matrix(( \
    [1, 0, 0, 0], \
    [0, cos(alpha), -sin(alpha), 0], \
    [0, sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0], \
    [0, 0, 0, 1] \
    ))
'''

m = Matrix(( \
    [1, 0, 0, 0], \
    [0, cos(alpha), 0, 0], \
    [0, sin(alpha), 1, 0], \
    [0, 0, 0, 1] \
    ))

cylinder.matrix_basis = m
bpy.context.scene.update() # is this call needed?

# prints different matrix than m
print(cylinder.matrix_basis)

# for debugging
print(cylinder.matrix_world)
```

This is the console output of it:

```
alpha=-17.10
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.9890, 0.1478, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, -0.1478, 0.9890, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.9890, 0.1478, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, -0.1478, 0.9890, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

The first printed matrix is the `matrix_basis`. As you can see, it differs from `m`. For example, the element of the second row, third column have to be 0 but is 0.1478.

I haven't apply any constraints to `cylinder`. So whats wrong by setting the `basis_matrix` in this way?

**Edit:**

In addtion to @mont29 's answer, I've found the following document:
[issues in orientation-matrix in Blender <2.50](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Migius/orientation_matrix&sa=U&ei=PUa4VLTzF9HjaMyqgoAO&ved=0CCIQ9QEwBg&usg=AFQjCNEqFzTvc3wZfOHpwoDAxGpZeDKL6g)

> Current implementation of orientation-matrix system in Blender is not reliable: there are limitations / some nasty problems with mirrored/non-uniform-scaled geometry in Blender
>
> Perhaps, it is not a bug, but a system design side-effect: insufficient/incomplete representation method of object orientation data with "all-in-one loc/rot/scale-matrix".

Yes, `m` **isn't orthogonal** (`m.is_orthogonal == False`), so Blender can't handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix_basis` only supports valid transform matrices - not a specialist, but by the look of it your `m` looks more like a shearing one?

Note that internally, there is no `matrix_basis` at all, Blender only stores translation/rotation/scaling separately, and converts them to/from RNA's `matrix_basis`. So if a matrix cannot be represented by a translation, rotation and scaling, then you cannot expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As @mont29 [answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47499/13128), your matrix produces a shear transformation, and those are not supported by Blender (at least in 2.91 as of writing this answer).

What you can do is shear the *mesh data* and reset the transform, if you can afford losing the latter. To match your sample code above, the following lines would help already:

```py
cylinder.data.transform(m)  # data is the Mesh
cylinder.data.matrix_world = Matrix.Identity(4)
```

I had the same issue importing model data with transformation matrices exported by another DCC tool in which some meshes were sheared. I first checked if their transformation matrix contained a shear by them [not being orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1022694/114154), and then applied the shear on the mesh data, only retaining the translation in that case:

```py
from bpy import context as C

# A sample sheared matrix, as loaded from file or whatever
m = Matrix((
    (-10.5924, -0.0638, -0.7292, 666.0000),
    (  8.0741,  0.0487, -0.9566, 818.0000),
    ( -0.0297, -1.8306,  0.0000,  51.0000),
    (  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,   1.0000)))

# A matrix is sheared if it is not orthogonal.
m33 = m.to_3x3()
if m33.is_orthogonal:  # allow only rotation
# ... or ...
if m33.is_orthogonal_axis_vectors:  # allow rotation and scale
    # Matrix is not sheared, can be represented directly in Blender
    C.object.matrix_world = m
else:
    # Matrix is sheared, apply shear to mesh data.
    C.object.data.transform(m33.to_4x4())
    # Only use translation in world matrix.
    C.object.matrix_world = m.translation
```